# Get class of appended ajax jquery data

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="loadhere></div>
```

Ajax snippet

```
  $('#loadhere').append('<span id="1" class="trash">     </span>');

$('.trash').click(function(){
   var x=$(this).attr('id');
 });
```

My problem i was not able to get the data of appended jquery data

Comment: Its appended by jquery

Comment: Code shown [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/ot5bxk4b/). There is something not shown that is causing your issue. Are you calling `$('.trash').click..` in same order as shown after the append? If not use event delgation

Comment: I cant get the id or even the class of the jquery appended data

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','.trash',function(){...` instead

Comment: @charlieft it work and I read about event delegation thanks a lot im new in web dev. Need to read a lot of stuff

Answer (score 1):

1. Element is appended and there needs event delegation
2. Use .on()

$(document).on("click",".trash",function(){ var x=$(this).attr('id'); });

Answer (score -1):

maybe you need to pass the handler as an argument to the function?

```
$('.trash').click(function(handler){
   var x=handler.attr('id');
 });
```

Comment: first argument of a jQuery event handler is the `event` object...not the element